# Force mouseover/hover effect over element

Tags: jquery

I want to force a hover effect over one element when hovering over another:

```
<div class="portfolio-item-holder">
   <div class="portfolio-item-hover-content"></div>
</div>


$('portfolio-item-hover-content').on('mouseover',function(){
        $('portfolio-item-holder').trigger('mouseover');
});
```

But this is not working.

Any help?

Comment: Your question and your http://jsfiddle.net/FCxfR/21/ don't match. What behaviour do you want ? Trigger the portofolio animation when hovering over the content ? or trigger the content animation when hovering over the portofolio ?

Comment: the latter yes, I got my code mixed up in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm, you forgot `.`

```
$('.portfolio-item-hover-content').on('mouseover',function(){
        $('.portfolio-item-holder').trigger('mouseover');
});
```

Comment: yeah thank you, but it still does not trigger a mouseover...I am using this theme: http://demo.s5themes.com/?theme=simplecorp and i want to do the hover animation when you hover over the box title as well ('Some of Our Featured Projects')

Comment: You need to show some more code for that..If possible create a fiddle.

Comment: note the following: I must simulate a mouseover, I cannot use just use CSS on the other element as well (the element with no :hover )

Comment: you will see that I swapped around the order of the divs inside the jquery function...

Answer (score 5):

You can't set the hover style using jQuery. I would recommend making a hover class in your css and applying it using addClass:

**CSS:**

```
.portfolio-item-holder:hover,
.portfolio-item-holder.hover {
    // these styles will be applied when naturally hovered
    // and when elements with the class "portfolio-item-holder"
    // also have the class "hover"
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.portfolio-item-hover-content').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $('.portfolio-item-holder').addClass('hover')
});
```

And you can remove it on mouseleave:

```
$('.portfolio-item-hover-content').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $('.portfolio-item-holder').removeClass('hover')
});
```

Comment: that is not the question. I could easily do this with CSS, but I am constricted to use the jQuery hover function...

Comment: Sorry, you can't set hover style using jQuery. This is your best option. How can you be 'constricted' to the hover function?

Comment: It is because of the theme I am using. When I change the CSS, the animation used inside the theme messes around. I think this is the only way of doing this - see theme : http://demo.s5themes.com/?theme=simplecorp.

Comment: let me try it and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

[`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) does not bind handlers to `mouseover/mouseout`, it binds them to `mouseenter/mouseleave`.

You can trigger the correct event : http://jsfiddle.net/FCxfR/26/

Note that you may observe weird behaviour with the animation ([`mouseover/mouseout`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) and [`mouseenter/mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) behave differently - see the examples at the end of each documentation's page)

---

See if the plugin doesn't allow you to do what you want (trigger the animation on some other element).

Otherwise, you can hack your way by looking for the code snippet which animates the html, and, instead of using their framework, manually bind these two functions as handlers for `mouseenter/mouseleave` on your parent node.

You will also need to update the css accordingly, smth along the lines :

```
 //rules applying to
 .portfolio-item-hover-content:hover
 //should be replaced with rules applying to
 .portfolio-item-holder:hover .portfolio-item-hover-content
```

It goes without saying : you will then be the only one to know if this can break the behaviour of the plugin on the remainder of the page ...

Comment: could you maybe provide some code: look at my fiddle, I want to trigger the hover effect in the middle when infact hovering over the parent...jsfiddle.net/FCxfR/21

Comment: could you maybe look at my fiddle and see if you can apply it there

Comment: yeah I see what you mean, the animation is not smooth at all

Comment: Any fixes? Recommendations?

Comment: thank you, i see what you mean. Will try and see what i can do